# How to get the number of pixels count according to some condition in GLSL/WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl, fragment-shader

I am trying to get the count of the number of pixels whose value is below 0.89.
As the WebGL Shaders variable doesn't persist , I just tried a hack where I was computing the count in the last iteration or when texCoord is 1.0,1.0.

Currently I am trying the below code , is this correct and do we have a better approach for this?

`

```
void main() {
  //gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(u_texture, vec2(mytexcoord.x, mytexcoord.y)).rgb, 1.0);
  vec2 uv = mytexcoord;
  float ins = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y)).r;
  float neglectIntensityValue = 0.89453125;
  float blueVal = 0.00000000;
  vec2 onePixel = vec2(1.0, 1.0) / u_resolution;
  int pixelCount = 0;
  if (vec2(1.0) == mytexcoord) {
    //last iteration
    //loop through all the pixels to know the count
    const int totalPixels = 100000;//int(u_resolution.x * u_resolution.y);
    for (int i = 0; i < totalPixels; i++) {
      vec2 uv = vec2((float(i)) / 100000.0, 0.5);
      vec4 colorData = vec4(texture2D(u_texture, uv).rgb, 1.0);
      if (colorData.r < neglectIntensityValue) {
        pixelCount++;
      }
    } 
  }
  if (pixelCount > 1000) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ins, ins, ins, 1.0);
  } else {
    ins = 1.0 - ins;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ins, ins, ins, 1.0);
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this more efficiently using only the fragment shader.  Your pixel shader may crash on large textures, as it's not intended to be run for some long. You could randomly sample a subset of the pixels as an approximation, if that is sufficient.

For an efficient implementation, you could have the shader output a 1 or 0 into a render texture, and then aggregate that using log(n) pass of a different pixel shader, summing 2x2 pixels (or 4x4, or more) into 1 pixel in each pass. Obviously that would be quite a bit more complex to implement.